# Tizen wearable sensor API stops giving data after sometime

Tags: native, sensors, tizen-wearable-sdk, sensormanager, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am trying to make a tizen gear application in which I record **accelerometer and gyroscope** data of user activity for about an hour and give analytics based on this raw sensor data saved in a csv file.

I have a tizen wearable **hybrid application**. I am using native service application to retrieve sensor data, and further sending it to web application for writing into csv file.

Upon testing, I have observed that after few minutes of starting the data recording (after about 3-8 minutes) the sensor data is no longer received (seen from the logs in `sensor_callback()` function). Moreover, during the test scenarios, I have observed that **SHealth application** opens up and starts recording the dynamic workout activity of the user. Is it possible that SHealth application might be hindering my application from receiving sensor data? If yes, how could one possibly resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give here some code like how did you start sensor, collect data and stop sensor.

Comment: Hi Iqbal, I am using the sample code as described in this [link](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-tutorials/native-application/system/sensor?langredirect=1) to retrieve the sensor data

Comment: You may try the solution in this link. https://developer.tizen.org/forums/native-application-development/how-can-i-run-my-code-background-using-service-app-samsung-gear-s2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually nothing can be say without seeing any code. 
SHealth can be an issue but it is just a guess as you have not provided any logs that can show SHealth is an issue. 
I will suggest you to follow the sensor app workflow properly from the below guide. The guides also provided sample app.

- [Accessing Heart Rate Monitor (HRM) Sensor data for Native applications](https://developer.tizen.org/zh-hans/community/tip-tech/accessing-heart-rate-monitor-hrm-sensor-data-native-applications)
- [How to use Light Sensor in Tizen](https://developer.tizen.org/zh-hans/community/tip-tech/how-use-light-sensor-tizen)

Comment: Hi @Iqbal,  I am also facing the same problem for long but could reach to a solution.. I have done a offline analysis of my codes, and found no memory leaks either. I also use a service app to access Acc and gyro sensor. All my codes follow the links mentioned above in the answer. The Crash-info report after the crash is also not helpful, just says address not mapped to Object etc.. Please help if any one of you people have reached to a solution.

Comment: Its Exactly the same problem, service app, accessing Accelerometer, gyroscope and PPG sensor.. and running some signal processing algorithm on the incoming data. All runs good for some time (no fixed duration) and all of a sudden crashes. All my codes are written by following the tutorials give at the tizen website (native-wearable)